# Bootstrap 4 Dropdown not working

Tags: bootstrap-4

Not sure if it is just me, I am moving from bootstrap 3 to v4 and dropdown list is not working, even the simplest example copied from the bootstrap v4 dropdown session. The code below shows a button clickable but not dropping down any. I found out that at the 0.01sec after I refresh and I click on the button the dropdown menu appears. But any times after it is just not working. Here is my code

js

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-3ceskX3iaEnIogmQchP8opvBy3Mi7Ce34nWjpBIwVTHfGYWQS9jwHDVRnpKKHJg7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.3.7/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-XTs3FgkjiBgo8qjEjBk0tGmf3wPrWtA6coPfQDfFEY8AnYJwjalXCiosYRBIBZX8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-BLiI7JTZm+JWlgKa0M0kGRpJbF2J8q+qreVrKBC47e3K6BW78kGLrCkeRX6I9RoK" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/css/tether-theme-arrows-dark.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-AysaV+vQoT3kOAXZkl02PThvDr8HYKPZhNT5h/CXfBThSRXQ6jW5DO2ekP5ViFdi" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

HTML

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Action
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For me the issue was that I forgot to add the Js links.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `btn-group` class is no longer used for dropdowns in Bootstrap 4. Use the `dropdown` class for the parent:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Action
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Experienced the same issue with Alpha 4.0.6.

I've copied the .dropdown styles fra bootstrap.css 3.3.7 into dropdowns.less and it worked.

```
.dropup,
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: 0.3em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  content: "";
  border-top: 0.3em solid;
  border-right: 0.3em solid transparent;
  border-left: 0.3em solid transparent;
}

.dropdown-toggle:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.dropup .dropdown-toggle::after {
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 0.3em solid;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 10rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  margin: 0.125rem 0 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #292b2c;
  text-align: left;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
          background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.dropdown-divider {
  height: 1px;
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #eceeef;
}

.dropdown-item {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3px 1.5rem;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #292b2c;
  text-align: inherit;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: none;
  border: 0;
}

.dropdown-item:focus, .dropdown-item:hover {
  color: #1d1e1f;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #f7f7f9;
}

.dropdown-item.active, .dropdown-item:active {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #0275d8;
}

.dropdown-item.disabled, .dropdown-item:disabled {
  color: #636c72;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.show > .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

.show > a {
  outline: 0;
}

.dropdown-menu-right {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
}

.dropdown-menu-left {
  right: auto;
  left: 0;
}

.dropdown-header {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5rem 1.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  color: #636c72;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.dropdown-backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 990;
}

.dropup .dropdown-menu {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0.125rem;
}
```

Not a valid workaorund but it works :-)

Comment: Dropdowns are built on a third party library, Popper.js, which provides dynamic positioning and viewport detection. Be sure to include [popper.min.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js) before Bootstrap’s JavaScript. Check the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#overview).

Comment: As per @Zuul, Popper has to come BEFORE bootstrap.js. This was the issue that I was having.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your jQuery code

```
$('.dropdown').click(function(){
  $('.dropdown-menu').toggleClass('show');
});
```

Comment: Yes this is fine but also, need to add "$(this).toggleClass('show');" for the version 4.4.1...
$('.dropdown').click(function(){
        $('.dropdown-menu').toggleClass('show');
        $(this).toggleClass('show');
      });